# Convert a Map<String, List<Object>> to Map<String, List<ClassVariable>> using java streams

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a class example:

```java
class Test {
     String id;
     int a;
     TestObject1[] someObjectArray;
     TestObject2[] someOtherObjectArray;
}
```

I have a map of `Map<String, List<Test>>` where String is `"id"`. I need to convert these to
`Map<String, List<someObjectArray>>` and `Map<String, List<someOtherObjectArray>>` using streams.

Tried something like this but couldn't get anywhere.

```java
HashMap<String, List<Test>> map =
        map.entrySet().forEach( p -> map.computeIfAbsent(p, k -> 
               new ArrayList<>())).add(p);
```

Comment: Is the `String` in all cases, the `Id` from `Test`.  In other words, where is the String in the target maps coming from?

Comment: Yes its Id for all cases

Comment: For `List<someObjectArray>>` and `List<someOtherObjectArray>`, do you want `List<TestObject1[]>` and `List<TestObject2[]>` or `List<TestObject1>` and `List<TestObject2>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Map<String, List<Test>> initialMap = new HashMap<>();

Map<String, List<TestObject1>> firstMap = initialMap.entrySet()
    .stream()
    .collect(
        Collectors.toMap(
            Map.Entry::getKey,
            entry -> entry.getValue()
                .stream()
                .flatMap(test -> Arrays.stream(test.getSomeObjectArray()))
                .toList()
        )
    );

Map<String, List<TestObject2>> secondMap = initialMap.entrySet()
    .stream()
    .collect(
        Collectors.toMap(
            Map.Entry::getKey,
            entry -> entry.getValue()
                .stream()
                .flatMap(test -> Arrays.stream(test.getSomeOtherObjectArray()))
                .toList()
        )
    );
```

}

if `.toList()` is not resolving on the inner stream you can use `.collect(Collectors.toList())` instead.

Also, if you're expecting to process huge amount of data in such way it is really would be better for performance to use `for` loop

Comment: `getSomeOtherObjectArray` for the second map though.

Comment: @AlexeyVeleshko thx, fixed

Comment: Was able to use this get the solution I wanted. Thanks

Comment: Is there a way to add null checks to the Arrays.stream(test.getSomeOtherObjectArray()) array before collecting as a list? in Java 8 streams

Comment: @iamrogue Sure, just insert `.filter(s -> s != null)` between `.flatMap` and `.toList` lines.

Comment: this worked. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Since you didn't specify how or where to use streams I opted for a hybrid solution to avoid iterating (or streaming over) the source map twice.

I created bare minimum records for the classes to simplify the code.

```
record TestObject1() {
}

record TestObject2() {
}

record Test(String getId, int getA, TestObject1[] getSomeObjectArray,
        TestObject2[] getSomeOtherObjectArray) {
};

Map<String, List<Test>> mapOfTest = new HashMap<>();
Map<String, List<TestObject1[]>> mapOfTestObject1 = new HashMap<>();
Map<String, List<TestObject2[]>> mapOfTestObject2 = new HashMap<>();
```

- Iterate across the `entrySet` of the source `Map<String,List<Test>>`
- Then using `map.computeIfAbsent`, create the target List as needed for each resultant map.
- then stream the Test list to put each array its own list so it can be added to the proper map.

```
for (Entry<String, List<Test>> e : mapOfTest.entrySet()) {    
    mapOfTestObject1.computeIfAbsent(e.getKey(), v -> new ArrayList<>())
            .addAll(e.getValue()
                .stream().map(Test::getSomeObjectArray).toList());
    mapOfTestObject2.computeIfAbsent(e.getKey(), v -> new ArrayList<>())
            .addAll(e.getValue()
                .stream().map(Test::getSomeOtherObjectArray).toList());
}
```

For lack of information, I presumed the String was always the `id`.

Answer (score 0):

> *'... I have a map of `Map<String, List<Test>>` where String is `"id"`. I need to convert these to
> `Map<String, List<someObjectArray>>` and `Map<String, List<someOtherObjectArray>>` using streams. ...'*

Utilize the *[Collectors#toMap](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap(java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.Function))*, and *[Stream#flatMap](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap(java.util.function.Function))*, methods.
For the *toMap* *valueMapper* parameter, stream the *List*, creating a *flat-mapping* for each *array* *field*; either *someObjectArray*, or *someOtherObjectArray*.

Here is an example, using *arrays* of *Integer* and *Double*, respectively *a*, and *b*.

```java
Map<String, List<Test>> map = new HashMap<>() {{
    put("a", List.of(new Test("a", 1, new Integer[] { 1, 2, 3 }, new Double[] { .7, .8, .9 } )));
    put("b", List.of(new Test("b", 2, new Integer[] { 4, 5, 6 }, new Double[] { .4, .5, .6 } )));
    put("c", List.of(new Test("c", 3, new Integer[] { 7, 8, 9 }, new Double[] { .1, .2, .3 } )));
}};
```

```java
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toMap;
```

```java
Map<String, List<Integer>> a
    = map.entrySet().stream()
                    .collect(toMap(Map.Entry::getKey,
                                   x -> x.getValue().stream()
                                                    .flatMap(y -> Stream.of(y.a))
                                                    .toList()));

Map<String, List<Double>> b
    = map.entrySet().stream()
                    .collect(toMap(Map.Entry::getKey,
                                   x -> x.getValue().stream()
                                                    .flatMap(y -> Stream.of(y.b))
                                                    .toList()));
```

Output

```
{a=[1, 2, 3], b=[4, 5, 6], c=[7, 8, 9]}
{a=[0.7, 0.8, 0.9], b=[0.4, 0.5, 0.6], c=[0.1, 0.2, 0.3]}
```